# How can I auto-format Rust (and C++) code on commit automatically?

Tags: c++, rust, githooks, pre-commit-hook, rustfmt

I would like to automatically format the code when I do commit using `rustfmt` the same way as I did it before for `clang-format -i`. I.e. format only the lines of code which has been updated in the commit without touching other code. How to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It might be done using git pre-commit hook in the following way:

1. Add file `pre-commit` to the folder `.githooks` in your repo with the following text:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

exe=$(which rustfmt)

if [ -n "$exe" ]
then
    # field separator to the new line
    IFS=$'\n'

    for line in $(git status -s)
    do
        # if added or modified
        if [[ $line == A* || $line == M* ]]
        then
            # check file extension
            if [[ $line == *.rs ]]
            then
                # format file
                rustfmt $(pwd)/${line:3}
                # add changes
                git add $(pwd)/${line:3}
            fi
        fi
    done

else
    echo "rustfmt was not found"
fi
```

2. Run in your repo folder:

```sh
chmod +x .githooks/pre-commit
git config core.hooksPath .githooks
```

To make it work for `clang-format` you need to replace `rustfmt` with `clang-format -i` and do corresponding modifications in the check for file extension (`cpp\h\hpp\etc`).

Comment: the only question missing is if it is possible to do both rustfmt and clippy

Comment: I am wonder what is the value of using folder `.githooks` instead of the standard folder with hooks `.git/hooks`. Putting the above script into `.git/hooks/pre-commit` and fixing permissions works well.

Comment: I think no value, just another way of doing the same